# Are there any Indian Christian traditions (Liturgical or scriptural) where God is referred to as "Brahman"?

Tags: catholicism, names-of-god, translation, christianity-in-india

The title sums up the question.

The reason I ask is that historically Catholics have placed a heavy emphasis on inculturation when evangelising new cultures. Rather than introducing western words for God into a new culture, they often study the existing religion of a culture and try to work out what word is used for the "supreme being". As such, in China, the word λογος is translated as 道 and God receives names such as 神 and 天主, all of these Chinese words designed to refer to some conception of a supreme being. Similarly in Arabic bible translations the word Allah is used to refer to God, in an effort to draw on existing connotations that Muslims associate with the name.

So I was wondering if there is any tradition in any strand of Indian Christianity (Protestant, Catholic, or otherwise) where they refer to God as Brahman, because that is the name of the supreme, ultimate reality in Hinduism.